# JFileChooser's anomaly with MyComputer in Windows

Tags: java, windows, swing, jfilechooser

I created a file chooser using swing to select only images from a windows platform. I used a `FileFilter` to do that. The code of the `accept()` method overridden form the `FileFilter` class is:

```
public boolean accept(File f) {

    System.out.println("File is : " + f.getName() + "  " + f);

    if(f.isDirectory())
        return true;

    String ext = getExtension(f);    // returns extensions of the files.

    if(ext.equals("jpg") || ext.equals("jpeg") || ext.equals("gif") || ext.equals("tif") || ext.equals("tiff"))
        return true;
    else {
        return false;
}
```

It hangs when `MyComputer` is selected form the windows desktop. The following is the entry i get for MyComputer:

`File is ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}  Computer`

And the following is the error message I get:

```
File is ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}  Computer
File is lenovo  C:\Users\lenovo
File is ::{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}  Network
File is ::{031E4825-7B94-4DC3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}  Libraries
File is 4s.txt  C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\4s.txt
File is cs.bat - Shortcut.lnk  C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\cs.bat - Shortcut.lnk
File is kaushik.txt  C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\kaushik.txt
File is rel.txt  C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\rel.txt
File is SQL Developer.lnk  C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\SQL Developer.lnk
File is Get Started With Oracle Database 11g Express Edition .lnk  C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Get Started With Oracle Database 11g Express Edition .lnk
```

The following is displayed after double-clicking myComputer:

```
File is ::{416651E4-9C3C-11D9-8BDE-F66BAD1E3F3A}  ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\::{416651E4-9C3C-11D9-8BDE-F66BAD1E3F3A}

Exception in thread "Basic L&F File Loading Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gui.ImageFilter.accept(ImageFilter.java:26)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.accept(JFileChooser.java:1576)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel$LoadFilesThread$1.call(BasicDirectoryModel.java:230)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel$LoadFilesThread$1.call(BasicDirectoryModel.java:216)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Win32ShellFolderManager2.java:458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

However when i add another `if` condition right after `ext` is initialized:

```
if (ext == null)
    return false;
```

It runs fine. My question is if `MyComputer` is a directory why it was bothered by the `null` test? Shouldn't it have returned `true` at the directory test? On the other hand, if it is not a directory (which makes it a file, right?), then how is it still returning `true` and getting opened by the file chooser?
Or is their some other exceptional angle to it?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: On which operating system you are running the above sample ?

Comment: I made a sample test but it's working ok. I'm using Windows 7. I assume your issue is not related to MyComputer, because if you can select it from the list means that accept() method returned true for it.

Comment: @gyuri i am using windows 7 as well. Yes, accept() method returned true for it but only after the null test. My question was, why does it has to bother with the null test? Isn't mycomputer more like a directory actually? If not, then what it is?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you ran your code without the null condition MyComputer appeared in the JFileChooser list ?

Comment: It's not happening for me, but I suggest to use FileNameExtensionFilter instead your custom FileFilter. Hope this helps.

Comment: @GyuriMajercsik yes it appears in the list but the program hangs when i double click it. However, no such thing happens when i first use the null condition.

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem with MyComputer because it appears in the list with or without the null condition. Please check how `FileFilter` works [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html) .

As stated in the documentation:

> "A `FileFilter` can be set on a `JFileChooser` to keep unwanted files
>   from appearing in the directory listing".

So if `accept()` method returns `true`, means that the passed in `File` will appear in the list, false otherwise.

The application hangs because what MyComputer may contain. Put a log like below:

```
public boolean accept(File f) {
                System.out.println("File is : " + f);
                if(f.isDirectory())
                    return true;.....
```

Rerun the application without the null condition, in order to reproduce the issue, and update your question with the output you see. The answer will be there.

**Edit:**
I simulated the behaviour you have and I get below output, please update your question with similar output, at least the last 10 lines:

```
File is : Computer
File is : Network
File is : Libraries
File is : Homegroup
File is : C:\
File is : E:\
File is : F:\
Exception in thread "Basic L&F File Loading Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    at Main$1.accept(Main.java:17)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.accept(JFileChooser.java:1617)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel$LoadFilesThread.run0(BasicDirectoryModel.java:252)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel$LoadFilesThread.run(BasicDirectoryModel.java:228)
```

I hope this helps.

P.S.: an easier way to do the filtering is to use `FileNameExtensionFilter`

Comment: I have edited the question, plz have a look! I will definitely try `FileNameExtensionFilter` after this one is resolved.

Comment: One more important detail: which JDK are you using ?

Comment: I edit my answer. Please update the question accordingly. I'm just thinking if you have any device(s) connected to your PC and are present in My Computer if you open it in Explorer, other than your HDD partitions.

Comment: I am using jdk 1.6. The only other device connected to my laptop is my usb internet datacard.

Comment: Hmm... Try without the USB datacard. Also, let me know the list of items you see when you open Computer in Explorer. When I open Computer in Explorer I see: C:\ ; E:\  ; and DVD RW Drive (F:\)

Comment: @SurenderThakran Have you found any solution ? I'm curious what caused the issue.

Comment: Yes, now it is working fine. I tried running it without plugging-in the datacard and it ran fine. However, just now i ran it again with the datacard and it still ran fine. So no I have not found what had caused the problem earlier but everything seems to be fine now. Infact I am not even able to simulate the situation that caused the problem though I have done everything the same way I earlier did. Thanx for your help anyway. Though my problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587469/my-custom-jdialog-appears-minimized-and-jscrollpanes-scroll-disappears still persists.