# My custom JDialog appears minimized and JScrollPane's scroll disappears

Tags: java, image, swing, jscrollpane, jdialog

I have created a basic swing program which displays an image in a `JDialog` box after it has been selected through a `JFileChooser`. I have used a `JScrollPane` inside the dialog box and a `JLabel` on which image is added as an icon, inside the pane.

The following is the code I have used to construct the dialog box and its contents, the objects are already initialized with a simple new call:

```
    jDialog1.setTitle("Image");
    jDialog1.setModal(true);

    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jLabel1);
```

Netbeans has been used to build the GUI.

The following is the code I have used to load and display the image:

```
    int rval = jFileChooser1.showDialog(this, "Show");
    File f = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
    jDialog1.setTitle(jDialog1.getTitle() + " : " + f.getName());
    try {
        BufferedImage bf = ImageIO.read(f);
        jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bf));
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
    }
    jDialog1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jDialog1.setVisible(true);
    jDialog1.pack();
```

Though the image is loaded and displayed, the trouble is

- My dialog box appears in a minimized form in the upper left hand corner and i have to drag its corner to view the image. Including an image of the same.

  [image]
- The horizontal scroll of the scroll pane disappears long before the dialog box is fully extended and the image is fully displayed. Though the vertical scroll bar acts fine.

I have tried setting size and preferred size of both `JDialog` and `JLabel` but the problems still persist.

Thanx in advance!

**Note:** The horizontal scroll bar problem is solved by using the `pack()` method on the dialog box but the minimized dialog box is still there. Also, the dialog box now appears in the center of the screen as well.

Comment: Try calling pack() on created JDialog and to show it at center of your screen just call setLocationRelativeTo(null) on your JDialog's object.

Comment: @GyuriMajercsik thanx, the problem of the horizontal scroll bar is solved and the dialog box is appearing in the center of the screen but the dialog box is still in a minimized form.

Comment: @GyuriMajercsik have added the image of the minimised dialog box in the question.

Comment: You say "Netbeans has been used to build the GUI." Did you use the Design Editor or did you code the GUI yourself (or a mix)? If not, what layout manager are you using?

Comment: @Jaybob I have used the design editor to construct the GUI but the code mentioned in the second code block in the question is hand-written.

Comment: @SurenderThakran Do you mean the main program was created with the design editor and then you hand-wrote the code for the JDialog?

Comment: @Jaybob No, i mean that the code in the first code block is the one created by the design editor in the `initComponents()` method (it is not the complete code in the method ofcourse!). The code in the second code block is the one that i have written and is the event handler code of a JButton (again not the complete code, only the relevant bits). This JButton opens a file chooser through which an image file is choosen and that image is displayed in the dialog box.

Comment: @Jaybob i can post the complete code of the event handler if that is needed but it has nothing of relevance in it to the present problem.

Comment: I think this is probably a layout / JDialog problem, nothing to do with your logic code. Are you sure you still don't have any `.setSize()` or `.setPreferredSize()` calls anywhere?

Comment: @Jaybob No, i deleted them when they didn't seemed to be working. Also, the auto-generated code doesn't has any.

Comment: I believe you will get more help if you post your full code; do you use any thread in your code ? or everything is on EDT ?

Comment: @Jaybob and Gyuri Have added the complete code of the event handler in the question. Yes, everything is on EDT and no I have not used any other thread except for the main(though it doesn't holds much code) thread and EDT.

Comment: Make sure you are not swallowing the IOException,  in the catch block call ioe.printStackTrace().

Comment: @GyuriMajercsik I don't think that would reveal anything because the image is correctly loaded its just that the dialog box in minimized, when I extend it by dragging the corner the image gets displayed. Still I will give it a try.

Comment: @GyuriMajercsik Nope, nothing changed but i guess kleopatra might have got something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequence of method calls matters for modal dialogs, you must call the pack before making the dialog visible (because otherwise the pack wouldn't be executed before the dialog is closed):

```
dialog.pack();
// Edit: manually double its size:
dialog.setSize(dialog.getPreferredSize().width * 2, dialog.getPreferredSize().height * 2);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. Now a decent sized dialog box appears containing my image not the minimized one i have mentioned in the question. On a side note, is there any way I can make it even more bigger, maybe even a full-screen dialog box?

Comment: Also, why would packing needs to be done before making it visible? I mean, can't the dialog box change its appearance according to the specifications of the `pack()` method when it is already displayed on the screen?